# Use number pad of mac keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I have a Windows 10 desktop and I use a mac keyboard with number pad on it. Its model number is A1243 and its connected by USB. However I cant seem to get the right driver or configuration to get the number pad to actually work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It might help if you specified the exact model of the keyboard, and details about the PC. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'not working'? the 10-key generates no input, wrong input? Try toggling numlock in your bios/efi, as Macs have no numlock.

Comment: @tetsujin thanks for the comment .. that gave me an idea that led to my solution ;-)

Comment: Glad you got it :)

Answer (score 9):

Turns out that the problem was pressing the numlock key. I managed to do that by starting the On-Screen Keyboard from Windows 10, turning on the numeric key pad in the options and then pressing NumLock there.

That triggered my hardware keyboard number pad to work!

Answer (score 4):

Is case anyone else stumbles across this hitting the "clear" key, just above the 7 will toggle numlock for the apple keyboards on Windows 10.

Comment: confirmed that this works